# How many minutes:seconds are passed betweek the visit and the exit?

Tags: javascript

I have to develop a very small JS script that saves the time spent between "entry" and "exit" on a page. This script has to monitor the user when he

"enters on the page"

and when

"he exits." (read "exit" as closing the page or closing the browser)

Is it possible? I can use:

`www.example.com/enter.php` (requested when the user enters the page)

and

`www.example.com/exit.php` (requested when the users exits the page)

I have to save data to calculate how many `minutes:seconds` pass for each unique visit. (like Google Analitycs).

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/PUSQU/)):

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>

    var start = new Date().getTime();

    $(window).unload(function() {
        var total = new Date().getTime() - start;
        alert(total);
        // Ajax total back to server
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You won't know until #1 you write the script that sends the data back to your server, and #2 the user 'unloads' the page ;)

Comment: what? I don't understand.... with the first comment I wrote you I mean, that i can't know where the users are current on because with your script the server will know the "time" at the end... I would like to see the time (at the end) but know what are the pages the users are reading... ithink i have to send a message during the load of the page and another at the end(as you wrote)...what do you think?

Comment: @Dail you can only reliable know the duration, as Javascript will be getting the time from the client's clock. So duration must be sent at the end. There is nothing stopping you from sending data back to your server at *any* time though - if you want to send some data back at the start, nothing is stopping you :)

Comment: why the time from the client's clock? Can I not send the timestamp on the server, and then calculate the time elapsed myself? (only to know what is the "best" method)...